# Why my ubuntu freezes or crashes?

Tags: 15.10, crash

Ubuntu 15.10.
My MB is P8P67 M PRO and display card is NVIDIA GTX 760.
When I installed Ubuntu, the system just crashes every few minutes. Mouse, keyboard and any things are not responding, just the screen freezes.
Are my BIOS settings wrong?

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: just like installed windows and enable c6 cup report, it also let the pc crashs

Answer (score 0):

Install a proprietary Nvidia driver by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

Comment: I already use the default Nvidia driver 352  It has problem?